# soft back and home buttons overlapping app buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I have Table of buttons at the bottom of my activity, but soft back and home buttons are overlapping activity and obstructing the buttons.I searched a lot but could't find how to avoid this[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding the following in theme

```
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [fitsSystemWindows](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec) to make your activity interactive to system Window size.

Add below code in your `mainactivity_layout.xml` root

```
   android:fitsSystemWindows = "true"
```